# Eigen library memory usage for dynamic vectors

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, eigen, allocator

I have a binary file storing float32 objects (9748422*5 of them). From such a collection (190MB roughly in size), I'm creating a set of `Eigen::VectorXd` vectors (each with 5 components), thus 9748422 of them. The underlying type is `double`, hence roughly double the input size for storing them.

But, as luck has it, the process requires a total of 2.5GB. This is a log of the `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`:

```
    PageFaultCount: 0x000A3C40
    PeakWorkingSetSize: 0xA3C42000
    WorkingSetSize: 0xA3C42000
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x00004ED8
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x00004ED8
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x000057A8
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x000057A8
    PagefileUsage: 0xA3A9B000
    PeakPagefileUsage: 0xA3A9B000
```

I've tracked Eigen's internal allocator, and it indeed seems to "allocate" exactly the size I compute on paper. However, Eigen uses aligned_alloc for most of its dynamic vectors. Could this be generating this amount of havoc? If nothing comes to mind, could you recommend another place to look for an issue of why this is happening?

I cannot provide a compilable (online) cpp example, but here's a skeleton of what I'm doing:

```
struct SSCCE_struct
{
    Eigen::VectorXd m_data;
};

typedef std::vector<SSCCE_struct*> TVector;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TVector outputVertices;
    HANDLE bpcHandle;
    bpcHandle = CreateFileA("D:\\sample.bpc",              
        GENERIC_READ,          
        FILE_SHARE_READ,       
        NULL,                 
        OPEN_EXISTING,        
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        NULL);                 

    LARGE_INTEGER  len_li;
    GetFileSizeEx (bpcHandle, &len_li);
    INT64 len = len_li.QuadPart; //(len_li.u.HighPart << 32) | len_li.u.LowPart;

    unsigned long long noPoints = len / 20;
    unsigned long noPointsRead = 0;
    unsigned long long currPointIdx = 0;

    outputVertices.resize( noPoints );

    DebugTrace( "No points %lu \n", noPoints );

    float buffer[ 5 * 1024 ];
    DWORD noBytesRead = 0;
    do 
    {
        ReadFile(bpcHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &noBytesRead, NULL);
        noPointsRead = noBytesRead / 20;
        for (unsigned long idx = 0; idx < noPointsRead; ++idx )
        {
            outputVertices[ currPointIdx + idx ] = new SSCCE_struct();

            outputVertices[ currPointIdx + idx ]->m_data.resize(5);

            for (unsigned kdx = 0; kdx < 5; ++kdx)
            {
                outputVertices[ currPointIdx + idx ]->m_data[ kdx ] = buffer[ 5 * idx + kdx ];
            }
        }

        currPointIdx += noPointsRead;

    } while (noBytesRead);


    CloseHandle(bpcHandle);
}
}
```

*Later edit*:

I performed the test indicated in David's answer and the solution is to avoid dynamic allocations altogether. There are several combinations one can try out and here's the results for all of these:

1.

```
struct SSCCE_struct
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double,1,5> m_data;
};

typedef std::vector<SSCCE_struct*> TVector;
```

Yielding 1.4 GB (1.1 GB waste)

2.

```
 struct SSCCE_struct
 {
    Eigen::VectorXd m_data;
 };

 typedef std::vector< SSCCE_struct* > TVector;
```

Yielding 2.5 GB (2.2 GB waste)

3.

```
struct SSCCE_struct
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double,1,5> m_data;
};

typedef std::vector<SSCCE_struct> TVector;
```

Yielding 381 GB (with 40 MB of waste - totally reasonable and, perhaps, predictable).

Comment: `aligned_alloc` does not explain this. An SSCCE would be nice. Should be easy for you to make it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added a pseudoSSCCE (I'm afraid one cannot get it to compile online that easily :D - you need the data, Eigen, winapi and so on and so forth).

Comment: You don't need to make it compile online. And a sample input file would be nice too. Anyway, I wonder why you use `VectorXd` rather than `Vector5d`. The latter will surely be a lot more efficient.

Comment: It's just a hint, but you could cross check memory usage using `Eigen::Map` and `Eigen::Matrix<double,1,5>` (or `5,1` ofc) to rule out default eigen dynamic allocators. @DavidHeffernan I wouldn't be so sure. I think 5 or 6 was the borderline case when they measured performance. They advised to use dynamic for longer vectors. I can check references, 'cause my memory is blurry over this, but I am quite sure I read this somewhere.

Comment: @luk32 For memory it has to be more efficient to use a fixed size. Then you avoid heap allocation overhead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But you put it on stack, for very large matrices it might not be the best idea. More on this is the [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) section **Fixed vs. Dynamic size**. The thing was about vectorization, but I cannot find the specific tests I was refering to, so don't believe me, on the number. I think fixed allocators didn't use SIMD very good. However, it is true, that generally for large cases, `dynamic` will outperform `fixed` (at least in current implementations). Nevertheless, I would recommend checking it out!

Comment: @luk32 Nobody said anything about putting them on the stack.

Comment: @David, for the sample, try this: http://we.tl/Gj32c6gTj2

Comment: @luk32, tried it `Eigen::Matrix<double,1,5>`. The waste is now `1.5GB` , so down by 1 gig. What could this tell about the source of wasted memory? I'm checking the winapi for more advanced mem profiling options in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a lot of pointers here, and each pointer has allocation overhead. The pointers refer to small objects, and so the overhead is significant.

On top of that, dynamically allocated objects necessarily have more overhead than fixed size objects. That's because fixed size objects do not need to store matrix dimensions.

Here are the sources of your pointer overhead:

1. `Eigen::VectorXd` uses dynamically allocated storage. That means a pointer.
2. You store the objects in `std::vector<SSCCE_struct*>`. And that's another pointer, with overhead.

The most efficient way to store these objects is to remove the indirection. You can do that by switching to:

1. `Matrix<double, 5, 1>`. This is a fixed size object and so has no indirection. What's more, as explained above, it does not need to store the matrix dimensions at runtime because they are known at compile time. For such a small object that is significant.
2. Store the objects in `std::vector<SSCCE_struct>`. Again, you lose one level of indirection.

With these changes, the memory usage of your program, when compiled with release settings, drops to 383MB on my machine. That's much more in line with your expectations.

The big difference seems to be between `Eigen::VectorXd` and the fixed size object. If I use `Eigen::VectorXd` and `std::vector<SSCCE_struct>` then the memory usage jumps to 918MB. When I then go to `std::vector<SSCCE_struct*>` it makes a further jump to 1185MB.

These measurements will be highly dependent on the compiler. I've used VS2013 compiling 32 bit code.

Comment: will test it right now. But still, where does the memory (not speed) overhead come from? It doesn't make the slightest of senses for the overhead to actually be this high.. BTW, at some point I'll have to use `SSCCE_struct*` (pointers) since this is the basis of an algorithm that will scramble the data according to some more complicated logic. Sure, I could do with storing them normally and passing references..

Comment: ony my machine, the jump is more than twice your result. I wonder what it could be: memory fragmentation.. page faults? It's really eerie and I have to shamelessly confess that low-level tidbits are not my bread and butter.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation comes with an overhead. Each individual block of memory has an allocation header. You can see that in the difference between `std::vector<SSCCE_struct>` and `std::vector<SSCCE_struct*>`. The difference is 267MB. There are `9,748,422` elements in total and so the overhead is about 28 bytes. That seems reasonable to me. Don't allocate lots and lots of small blocks of memory is the message.

Comment: It won't be page faults. It will be down to the compiler and the runtime. I'm using VS2013.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! I'd say no (I'll accept the answer tomorrow) - you've helped a lot. The only puzzle is what does the compiler actually do to come up with such huge variations, but that should be put in another question.

Comment: You have not said which compiler you use, and whether release or debug

Comment: Right, sorry: VS2010, x64, Debug.

Comment: Debug heap allocation overhead is huge.

Comment: Indeed, quite huge. The worst case scenario difference is 1GB. I tested it now and the waste is 1.3 GB (total of 1.6 GB of process memory) under x64 Release. Nevertheless, it's still the worst case to use pointers everywhere. _An observation_: I remember profiling the memory with artificial data and I think there was no actual waste (I'll do it again just to be sure I didn't hit an odd spot).

Comment: It doesn't matter where the data comes from. The overheads are independent from the data.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I don't know what I profiled before :(. Again, many thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

I am not allowed to comment, so I will post one more answer, even though I think that the above answers actually explained the source of the wasted memory (huge number of allocations).

I understand that you want to work on a lot of penta so you are using a vector of struct SSCCE_struct, ie

```
std::vector<SSCCE_struct*> TVector;
```

Have you considered using

```
Eigen::Matrix< double, Dynamic, 5 > outputVertices;
outputVertices.resize( noPoints, 5 );
```

which would avoid the waste of memory. I would consider this also for vectorization (to help eigen/compiler to better vectorize whatever it is that you are doing with them) even though 5 is not a very convenient number for vectorization as 4 or 8.

edit: i realised I am 3 years late the moment I clicked post...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even if it's late (I have ultimately solved the said problem). And yes, you are right to indicate that suggestion. It is nevertheless the 101 of what some have dubbed *data oriented design* (https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/what-is-data-oriented-game-engine-design--cms-21052).

Comment: Thank you for the nice article!